# Weblogic : How to track session when cookies set secure and jsession id need to remove from URL

Tags: java, url-rewriting, session-cookies, weblogic-10.x

I am using web-logic 10.3.
I have set Cookies secure, and I start getting jsession id in URL.

In my JPF controller we are using annotation: `@jpf.Controller(loginRequired = true)`

When I modify weblogic.xml file 
for URL-Rewriting false, my application fails to track session.
Means from controller `NotLoggedInException` comes and application not logged off,
error comes there is no login user.

Could anyone please help so that I can remove jsession id from URL and cookies are remain set secure?

Comment: is there any solution, please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
When we set our cookies as secure,
it will be no longer shareable on HTTP so framework will create a jsession id and append this id to URL so that session tracking can be done.

But when we think about to disable URL Re-writing means to remove jsession Id from URl.

In this case just try to redirect your application on HTTPS from HTTP.

On HTTPS secure cookies will be shareable.

To redirect http to https you need to implement a tg in web.xml 

<security-constraint>
 ..................
 ..................
 <user-data-constraint>
  <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL<transport-guarantee>
 <user-data-constraint>
<security-constraint>
```